# Can BiFunction references be passed to methods expecting a functional interface?

Tags: java, java-8, lambda, bifunctor

I've always only used Java 6 and am right now catching up to learn what's new in Java 8. I was reading this article here:
http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/lambda-expressions-in-java-8/240166764?pgno=2

And it says:

> The Java API defines several generic functional interfaces in the
>   java.util.function package. One of the interfaces, BiFunction, describes functions with parameter types T and U and return type
>   R. You can save our string comparison lambda in a variable of that
>   type:

```
BiFunction<String, String, Integer> comp 
    = (first, second) -> Integer.compare(first.length(), second.length());
```

> However, that does not help you with sorting. There
>   is no Arrays.sort method that wants a BiFunction. If you have used a
>   functional programming language before, you may find this curious. But
>   for Java programmers, it's pretty natural. An interface such as
>   Comparator has a specific purpose, not just a method with given
>   parameter and return types. Java 8 retains this flavor. When you want
>   to do something with lambda expressions, you still want to keep the
>   purpose of the expression in mind, and have a specific functional
>   interface for it.

However, when I see this thread:
[How do you assign a lambda to a variable in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920039/how-do-you-assign-a-lambda-to-a-variable-in-java-8)

The answers to the question there suggest doing exactly what the quoted paragraph says you can't do.

So, is the information in the article incorrect, or am I mis-reading something here?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just assign that same lambda to a `Comparator` and use it in a sort invocation...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't see anything in the linked SO answer that contradicts the article.

Regular rules of the type system apply to **functional interface**.

If you declare a variable as `BiFunction<String,String,Integer> bifunc`, you will not be allowed to pass it to a method that requires `Comparator<String>` because `BiFunction<String,String,Integer>` is not a **subtype** of `Comparator<String>`.

The fact that functional types follow all the usual rules is what allowed this new functionality to be added with minimal perturbations.

And if you wish to make a `Comparator` out of a `BiFunction` all you have to do is add `::apply` like so:

```
BiFunction<String,String,Integer> bifunc = (a,b) -> 
                               Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length());

Arrays.sort(array, bifunc::apply);
```

Answer (score 3):

The article is correct in the sense, that you cant sort based on object of `BiFunction` type, but you always can using `Comparator`. But hey, they both can have the same body. For example:

```
private static void sort(Comparator<String> ls){
        Arrays.sort(someArray, ls);
}

Comparator<String> comp = (String f1, String f2) -> Integer.compare(f1.length(), f2.length());
sort(comp);

BiFunction<String, String, Integer> func = (String f1, String f2) -> Integer.compare(f1.length(), f2.length());
sort((String f1, String f2) -> Integer.compare(f1.length(), f2.length())); //line-4

sort(func) // compiler error
```

Above at line-4, you are able to pass a lambda which is exactly same as `func`. But you still cannot pass `func` to `sort`. Lambdas in java8 are an implementation of some [FunctionalInterface](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html). Functional Interfaces get their type based on its reference type. Thats how the same lambda on initialization can be either a `BiFunction` or `Comparator`.

But once a lambda is constructed and it gets it type, then you cant change it. Hence you cannot pass `func` of type `BiFunction` to sort which expects `Comparator`

Answer (score 2):

The article is correct. You can not assign e.g. a `BiFunction` to a `Comparator`.

With that being said, this [great article](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html) written by Brian Goetz explains the problem in a nice way.

> When the compiler encounters a lambda expression, it first lowers (desugars) the lambda body into a method whose argument list and return type match that of the lambda expression

So, a lambda can be *desugared* - but what does that mean? Well, basically it means that a new method (may) be created that somehow matches the lamdba.

```
class A {
    public void foo() {
        List<String> list = ...
        list.forEach( s -> { System.out.println(s); } );
    }
}
```

The code above will be *desugared* to something like this:

```
class A {
    public void foo() {
        List<String> list = ...
        list.forEach( [lambda for lambda$1 as Consumer] );
    }

    static void lambda$1(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

So, in the case of the `BiFunction` and `Comparator`. The provided lambda can be assigned to both:

```
// Assign the lambda to a BiFunction
BiFunction<String, String, Integer> b1 =
        (first, second) -> Integer.compare(first.length(), second.length());

// Assign the lambda to a Comparator
Comparator<String> c1 =
        (first, second) -> Integer.compare(first.length(), second.length());

// But, once the lambda has been assigned to a type you can not reassign it
BiFunction<String, String, Integer> b2 = c1; // <-- Error
```

Note that once a lambda has been assigned to a type (`BiFunction` or `Comparator`) then it can not be reassigned, *even if the lambda expression matches*.

Comment: When you take over code snippets from this old article you should take the chance to update them to the actual API. What was called `Block<String>` back then has become `Consumer<String>`. Sticking with the old names can be confusing for readers not aware of the history.