# Java Stream API storing lambda expression as variable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This title sounds stupid even to me, but there must be at least somewhat clever way to achieve such effect and I don't know how else to explain it. I need to sort array using sorted in stream API. Here is my stream so far:

```
Arrays.stream(sequence.split(" "))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .boxed()
        .sorted((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b))
        .forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
```

Now I have two different sorts of course - ascending and descending and the sort I need to use is specified in the user input. So what I want to do is having something like switch with 2 cases: "ascending" and "descending" and a variable to store the lambda expression respectively:

```
switch(command) {
    case "ascending": var = a.compareTo(b);
    case "descending": var = b.compareTo(a);
}
```

Then I my sorted looks like:

```
 .sorted((a, b) -> var)
```

I got the idea in a python course I attended. There it was available to store an object in variable, thus making the variable "executable". I realize that this lambda is not an object, but an expression, but I'm asking is there any clever way that can achieve such result, or should I just have

```
if(var)
```

and two diferent streams for each sort order.

Comment: You can assign lambdas to variables (they're just another way of writing anonymous inner classes), have a look here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920039/how-do-you-assign-a-lambda-to-a-variable-in-java-8

Comment: this lambda `(int a, int b) -> a.compareTo(b)` is in fact an anonymous class object implementing `IntBiFunction` interface.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou It can implement *arbitrary* interfaces, as long as they only have one method with the appropriate signature (e.g. `IntBinaryOperator`). The problem is that there is no "generic superinterface" that represents *all* these types.

Comment: @Marco13 oh, I see. Thank you for clarification (and of course, I meant `IntBinaryOperator`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is not stupid at all. Answering it in a broader sense: Unfortunately, there is no generic solution for that. This is due to the type inference, which determines *one particular type* for the lambda expression, based on the target type. (The section about [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) may be helpful here, but does not cover all details regarding lambdas).

Particularly, a lambda like `x -> y` does not have any type. So there is no way of writing

*`GenericLambdaType`*`function = x -> y;`

and later use `function` as a drop-in replacement for the actual lambda `x -> y`.

For example, when you have two functions like

```
static void useF(Function<Integer, Boolean> f) { ... }
static void useP(Predicate<Integer> p) { ... }
```

you can call them both with the same lambda

```
useF(x -> true);
useP(x -> true);
```

but there is no way of "storing" the `x -> true` lambda in a way so that it later may be passed to **both** functions - you can only store it in a reference with *the type that it will be needed in* later:

```
Function<Integer, Boolean> f = x -> true;
Predicate<Integer>         p = x -> true;
useF(f);
useP(p);
```

---

For your particular case, the [answer by Konstantin Yovkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36333323/3182664) already showed the solution: You have to store it as a `Comparator<Integer>` (ignoring the fact that you wouldn't have needed a lambda here in the first place...)

Comment: You could still `useP(f::apply)`

Comment: @DidierL Sure, but this implies that you already stored it with a *known* type (namely, `Function`, or any other type where the method is called `apply`....)

Answer (score 8):

You can switch between using `Comparator.reverseOrder()` and `Comparator.naturalOrder`:

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = youWantToHaveItReversed ? Comparator.reverseOrder(): Comparator.naturalOrder();
Arrays.stream(sequence.split(" "))
      .map(Integer::valueOf)
      .sorted(comparator)
      .forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
```

Comment: The method reference `Integer::compareTo` is as obsolete as a comparator implemented as `(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)`. If the items are comparable, you can just use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, e.g. `Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();`. Or you get rid of the follow-up `if` statement and do a simple `Comparator<Integer> comparator = youWantToHaveItReversed? Comparator.reverseOrder(): Comparator.naturalOrder();`

Answer (score 0):

In Lambdas you can use a functionblock
`(a,b) -> { if(anything) return 0; else return -1;}`