# What does ()->{} represent in java?

Tags: java, operators

What does ()->{} represent in java?. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the arrow operator, '->', do in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java)

Comment: You should at least show us this in the context of some actual code.

Comment: Read up on Java 8 Lambdas

Comment: It's a "lambda", a way of representing functions, or in Java's case, anonymous implementations of functor interfaces.

Comment: Extremely sorry for that . I have seen this operator in many function calls, so I thought it is general one. 
Latest encounter in the following function call
executorService.execute(() -> { sqs.receiveMessage(); processMessage();
});

Comment: It is "a general one". Isn't​ it?

Answer (score 4):

It's a lambda expression, basically a concise way of writing a function. `()->{}` is a function that takes no arguments and does nothing. A longer way of writing the same thing:

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // nothing
    }
};
```

Comment: Why would someone write a function that does **nothing**?

Comment: It could actually be useful as a NOOP default value for something. E.g. an optional callback because if the default is `()->{}` then you don't need to check for null. Basically the Null Object pattern

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider old way of writing functions(i.e methods) in java.

```
//lets assume this is inside calculate class
public int sum(int a, int b){
     return a+b;
}
```

in java 8 we have something called lambda's in which we have concept called passing behaviours(methods) to another behaviour(methods).

in those case we use syntax like `(a,b) -> return a+b`;

```
BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> sum= (a,b)->{
            return a+b;
        };

System.out.println(sum.apply(1, 2));
```

Even we can store Function in a variable and pass to another function. you 
   can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920039/how-do-you-assign-a-lambda-to-a-variable-in-java-8)

now lets see about syntax `(a,b) ->{ return a + b};`
   (a,b) are arguments to function;

and the line of code inside {} represent the behaviour. -> is to separate 
   both left and right expressions.

you can explore more about java8 and lambda over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)